# Trying to add error message in case key not found in array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, search

I'm working on a rather piece of trivial code; I'm trying to add an error message that searches an array for a specific key. (Not an error message in a literal sense, just a print statement stating that the key / searched int is not in the array.)

The following is the function and the driver code I've written for it.

```C
#include <stdio.h>

size_t find_element(size_t len, int arr[len], int key)
{
    size_t pos = (size_t)-1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t len = 7;
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int key = 5;

    printf("IDX: %zu ", find_element(len, arr, key));

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, find_element returns the position of the desired key in the array. However I'm having trouble printing out an error message if the key isn't found.

What I'm trying to achieve in output is:

```
'Key not in the array'
```

*After* having scanned the entire array, the error message is displayed.

So far I've tried the following things:

```
else
{
    pos = i;
    printf("%zu is not the correct Index! \n", pos);
    continue;
}
```

Which absolutely doesn't work seeing as it just tells the user which indices aren't the correct ones.

I've also tried a goto FAIL statement, however that isn't it either.

I suspect I have to use the continue statement in some other fashion, but have no clue on how to implement it.

Comment: Check what the function *returns* and print the error message there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign -1 to pos initially. and if key not found, it will stay as -1 .

```
int find_element(size_t len, int arr[len], int key)
{
    int pos = -1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

If the function returns -1, it means that key not found, otherwise function will return index of key.

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t len = 7;
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int key = 5;
    int result = find_element(len, arr, key);
    if(result==-1){
        printf("Key not in the array");
    }
    else{
    printf("IDX: %d ", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I know size_t is unsigned int and it cannot assign to negative number

Comment: That worked and was simple, I couldn't figure it out on my own for the love of it... tried messing a bit with the main function, but never thought about checking it with if statements there. Thank you.